# Call for the wordpress text field

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, field

I am working in an existing theme from my company. They have a special page template. This template uses custom fields you can fill in, they then get displayed on the page.

The general text field that you see when editing a page is not shown on the page however. (it is in the dashboard environment.) This is what the page template looks like:

```
    <?php get_header() ?>
<?php the_post() ?> 
<!-- start content -->
        <div id="content">

            <div class="col left">                      
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-widgets' ); ?>
           </div>

           <h1 class="mobiletitle" style="text-align:center;"><?php the_title() ?> </h1>

           <div id="center">




              <div class="two-col">


               <?php                
                if( get_field('slider') )
                { ?>

                    <div class="rslides_container">
                        <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">

                    <?php while( has_sub_field("slider") )
                    {

                            $variable = get_sub_field('image'); ?>

                            <li><img src="<?php echo $variable;?>" alt="Magic Stables"></li>

                        <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>  



                <?php } ?>


                 <h1 class="maintitle" style="text-align:center;"><?php the_title() ?> </h1>

                 <div class="horseinfo">   
                 <table>
                    <?php if(get_field('naam_paard')) { ?>   
                      <tr>
                            <td><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') { ?>
                            Naam:
                         <?php } else { ?>
                         Name:
                         <?php } ?></td>
                            <td><?php the_field('naam_paard'); ?></td>                     
                    </tr>  
                     <?php } ?>                 
                 <?php if(get_field('afstamming')) { ?>   
                      <tr>             
                          <td><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') { ?>
                            Afstamming:
                         <?php } else { ?>
                         Breed:
                         <?php } ?></td>
                         <td><?php the_field('afstamming'); ?></td>                     
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>

                 <?php if(get_field('geslacht')) { ?>   
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') { ?>
                            Geslacht:
                         <?php } else { ?>
                         Gender:
                         <?php } ?></td>
                         <td><?php the_field('geslacht'); ?></td>                     
                    </tr>  
                     <?php } ?>                 
                 <?php if(get_field('geboortejaar')) { ?>   
                        <tr>
                   <td><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') { ?>
                            Geboortejaar:
                         <?php } else { ?>
                         Year of Birth:
                         <?php } ?></td>
                         <td><?php the_field('geboortejaar'); ?></td>                     
                    </tr>  
                    <?php } ?>
                 <?php if(get_field('geboortejaarkleur')) { ?>   
                    <tr> 
                    <td><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') { ?>
                            Geboortejaarkleur:
                         <?php } else { ?>
                         Birth color:
                         <?php } ?></td>
                         <td><?php the_field('geboortejaarkleur'); ?></td>                     
                         </tr>
                     <?php } ?>                
                <?php if(get_field('stokmaat')) { ?>   
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') { ?>
                            Stokmaat:
                         <?php } else { ?>
                         Height:
                         <?php } ?></td>
                         <td><?php the_field('stokmaat'); ?></td>                     
                    </tr>  
                    <?php } ?>

                <?php if(get_field('fokker_naam')) { ?>   
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') { ?>
                            Fokker:
                         <?php } else { ?>
                         Breeder:
                         <?php } ?></td>
                         <td><?php the_field('fokker_naam'); ?></td>                     
                    </tr>                   
                    <?php } ?>                
                 <?php if(get_field('fokker_plaats')) { ?>   
                      <tr>
                        <td><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') { ?>
                            Fokker plaats:
                         <?php } else { ?>
                         Breeding place:
                         <?php } ?></td>
                         <td><?php the_field('fokker_plaats'); ?></td>                     
                         </tr>
                   <?php } ?>                 
                  <?php if(get_field('overig')) { ?>   
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='nl') { ?>
                            Overig:
                         <?php } else { ?>
                         Other:
                         <?php } ?></td>
                            <td><?php the_field('overig'); ?></td>                     
                         </tr> 
                     <?php } ?> 

                 </table>
                 </div>
                 <br><br> 


                 <?php if(the_content()) { ?>      
                 <div class="one-col">          
                    <?php the_content() ?>                  
                 </div> 
                  <?php } ?>                    

                <?php if(get_field('linkerkolom')) { ?>     
                    <div class="two-col-1">
                     <?php the_field('linkerkolom'); ?>
                    </div>
                  <div class="two-col-2">
                     <?php the_field('rechterkolom'); ?>
                    </div>
                 <?php } ?>  
              </div>


           </div>
           <div class="col right">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'right-widgets' ); ?>           
           </div>


<?php get_footer() ?>
```

I see that with this line you make the text from a custom form appear:

```
<?php the_field('fokker_naam'); ?>
```

Now, how do I get the normal field to appear on the page again? What is the name of this field?

I need to use this field because I would like to use the editor, to create font styles and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main post content is accessed via `the_content()` function:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now, thank you for your time!